# project file not running on the targeted api

Tags: android, eclipse

the following line are the errors that i am getting from the console

```
[2012-10-01 20:34:24 - User Tracking Client] Android Launch!
[2012-10-01 20:34:24 - User Tracking Client] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-01 20:34:24 - User Tracking Client] Performing com.buet.tracker.Copy_2_of_MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-01 20:34:30 - User Tracking Client] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avd4.0.3'
[2012-10-01 20:34:32 - User Tracking Client] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-10-01 20:34:32 - User Tracking Client] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-10-01 20:36:21 - User Tracking Client] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-10-01 20:36:21 - User Tracking Client] Uploading User Tracking Client.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-10-01 20:36:21 - User Tracking Client] Installing User Tracking Client.apk...
[2012-10-01 20:38:26 - User Tracking Client] Failed to install User Tracking Client.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-10-01 20:38:26 - User Tracking Client] (null)
[2012-10-01 20:38:26 - User Tracking Client] Failed to install User Tracking Client.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2012-10-01 20:38:26 - User Tracking Client] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
[2012-10-01 20:38:26 - User Tracking Client] Launch canceled!
```

the emulator is running normally but it shows from the console that it is not detecting the api

Answer (score 0):

Did you see in Eclipse the proper library inside your project?

Click with the right button over your Project and go to properties. In the Android tab, you can set the correct target of your project. Check If you have one selected.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly open your emulator from android sdk, once it gets loaded, then from eclipse manually run your app in the current emulator.

Hope this helps.